# init.d values for separate redis-server instances

Tags: redis

I need to clear a concept. I have two redis servers running on a single VM. Server#1 connects via TCP, server#2 connects via a UNIX socket. I'm on the cusp of converting the TCP server to UNIX as well.

An excerpt from the `init.d` script for server#1 is:

```
DAEMON=/usr/bin/redis-server
DAEMON_ARGS=/etc/redis/redis.conf
NAME=redis-server
DESC=redis-server

RUNDIR=/var/run/redis
PIDFILE=$RUNDIR/redis-server.pid
```

The comparable excerpt from the `init.d` script for server#2 is (which has its own config):

```
DAEMON=/usr/bin/redis-server
DAEMON_ARGS=/etc/redis/redis-2.conf
NAME=redis2-server
DESC=redis2-server

RUNDIR=/var/run/redis
PIDFILE=$RUNDIR/redis2-server.pid
```

Both servers are currently up and running. My question is: how come `DAEMON` is kept the same for both servers? Why wasn't a separate executable needed?

I configured the two servers using config from various internet forums. While it works, I've failed to understand the significance of the `DAEMON` value, given it remains the same for both server instances. Is it because the executable is fed different config files, and this the same DAEMON is able to handle multiple server instances? Being a beginner, I'd really like some expert opinion on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open terminal (or cmd). Now open it again. You have two copies open, but they are both using the same executable.

You're doing the same with redis: DAEMON is just saying where to find the program, and since you're happy to use the same version of redis for both, you can use the same path for both DAEMON values, each instance of which has its own ID stored in the PIDFILE, which is why they need to be different paths or they will interfere with each other.